# (oidc-client + React and Typescript) OidcClient.readSigninResponseState: No matching state found in storage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I saw that there are already threads on the subject but they are mostly dead or in any case without any real solution.

I'm implementing a `react` and `typescript` client, in it I have installed the `oidc-client` module to be able to communicate with an external `identityserver4` service.
Actually it seems that the flow is working, logins and logouts work fine with the right redirects. The only thing I noticed is that when I log in and I am redirected to the page that completes the login (`/signin-callback`), this error is triggered for a moment but then with the next render its redirect me to the home with the user correctly logged in.
This is the error:

[image: no matching state error]

the configuration i send to the `idp`:

```js
    public static config: UserManagerSettings = {
        authority: 'https://idservices.idphost.it/',
        client_id: 'myapp_client_id',
        client_secret: 'myapp_client_secret',
        redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:9099/signin-callback',
        silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:9099/silent-renew',
        response_type: 'code', // 'code'
        scope: 'openid profile email roles',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:9099/signout-oidc',
        loadUserInfo: true,
        revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
    };
```

this is my `authservice class`:

```js
    import { UserManager, Log, User } from 'oidc-client';
    import Constants from '../helpers/const/Constants';

    export const AuthenticationResultStatus = {
        Redirect: 'redirect',
        Success: 'success',
        Fail: 'fail',
    };

    export type UserState = {
        redirectPath?: string;
    };

    export type AuthResponse = {
        status: string;
        message?: string;
        userState?: UserState;
    };

    function buildError(message: string): AuthResponse {
        return { status: AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail, message };
    }

    function buildSuccess(userState: UserState): AuthResponse {
        return { status: AuthenticationResultStatus.Success, userState };
    }

    function buildRedirect(): AuthResponse {
        return { status: AuthenticationResultStatus.Redirect };
    }

    type CallbackSub = {
        callback: () => void;
        subscription: number;
    };

    export class AuthService {
        private userManager: UserManager;

        private callbacks: CallbackSub[] = [];

        private nextSubscriptionId = 0;

        private currentUser: User = null;

        public constructor(isClient = true) {
            this.userManager = isClient ? new UserManager(Constants.globalOidcConfig) : new UserManager(Constants.globalOidcApiConfig);
            // Logger
            Log.logger = console;
            Log.level = Log.WARN;

            this.userManager.events.addAccessTokenExpiring(() => {
                console.log('token expiring');
                void this.trySilentSignIn();
            });

            this.userManager.events.addAccessTokenExpired(() => {
                console.log('token expired');
                void this.userManager.removeUser().then(() => {
                    this.updateState(null);
                });
            });

            this.userManager.events.addSilentRenewError((e) => {
                console.log('silent renew error', e.message);
            });

            this.userManager.events.addUserLoaded((user) => {
                console.log('user loaded', user);
            });

            this.userManager.events.addUserUnloaded(() => {
                console.log('user unloaded');
            });

            this.userManager.events.addUserSignedIn(() => {
                console.log('user logged in to the token server');
            });

            this.userManager.events.addUserSignedOut(() => {
                console.log('user logged out of the token server');
            });
        }

        updateState(user: User): void {
            this.currentUser = user;
            this.notifySubscribers();
        }

        subscribe(callback: () => Promise<void>): number {
            this.callbacks.push({
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
                callback,
                subscription: this.nextSubscriptionId,
            });

            this.nextSubscriptionId += 1;
            return this.nextSubscriptionId - 1;
        }

        unsubscribe(subscriptionId: number): void {
            const subscriptionIndex = this.callbacks
                .map((element, index) => (element.subscription === subscriptionId ? { found: true, index } : { found: false }))
                .filter((element) => element.found === true);
            if (subscriptionIndex.length !== 1) {
                throw new Error(`Found an invalid number of subscriptions ${subscriptionIndex.length}`);
            }

            this.callbacks.splice(subscriptionIndex[0].index, 1);
        }

        notifySubscribers(): void {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.callbacks.length; i++) {
                const { callback } = this.callbacks[i];
                callback();
            }
        }

        async getUser(): Promise<User> {
            if (this.currentUser?.profile == null) {
                this.currentUser = await this.userManager.getUser();
            }

            return this.currentUser;
        }

        async getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
            const user = await this.userManager.getUser();
            return user && user.access_token;
        }

        async trySilentSignIn(): Promise<User> {
            await this.userManager
                .signinSilent()
                .then((user: User) => {
                    this.updateState(user);
                    return user;
                })
                .catch((error: Error) => {
                    void this.userManager.getUser().then((user: User) => {
                        console.log('silent renew error', error.message);
                        this.updateState(user);
                        return undefined;
                    });
                });

                return undefined;
        }

        // We try to authenticate the user in two different ways:
        // 1) We try to see if we can authenticate the user silently. This happens
        //    when the user is already logged in on the IdP and is done using a hidden iframe
        //    on the client.
        // 3) If the method above fails, we redirect the browser to the IdP to perform a traditional
        //    redirect flow.
        async signin(userState: UserState): Promise<AuthResponse> {
            try {
                // await this.userManager.signinRedirect({ useReplaceToNavigate: true, state: userState });
                // return buildRedirect();
                const silentUser = await this.userManager.signinSilent({ useReplaceToNavigate: true, state: userState });

                this.updateState(silentUser);
                return buildSuccess(silentUser.state as UserState);
            } catch (silentError) {
                // User might not be authenticated, fallback to redirect
                console.log('Silent authentication error: ', silentError);

                try {
                    await this.userManager.signinRedirect({ useReplaceToNavigate: true, state: userState });
                    return buildRedirect();
                } catch (redirectError) {
                    console.log('Redirect authentication error: ', redirectError);
                    return buildError(redirectError as string);
                }
            }
        }

        async completeSignin(url?: string): Promise<AuthResponse> {
            try {
                const user = (await this.getUser()) || (await this.userManager.signinCallback(url));
                const userState = user.state as UserState;
                this.updateState(user);
                return buildSuccess(userState);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('There was an error signing in: ', error);
                return buildError('There was an error signing in.');
            }
        }

        // Redirect the browser to the IdP to perform a traditional
        //    post logout redirect flow.
        async signout(): Promise<AuthResponse> {
            try {
                console.log('entered in logout');
                await this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
                return buildRedirect();
            } catch (redirectSignOutError) {
                console.log('Redirect signout error: ', redirectSignOutError);
                return buildError(redirectSignOutError as string);
            }
        }

        async completeSignout(url?: string): Promise<AuthResponse> {
            try {
                await this.userManager.signoutCallback(url);
                this.updateState(null);
                return buildSuccess(null);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('There was an error trying to log out ', error);
                return buildError(error as string);
            }
        }
    }

    const authService = new AuthService();

    export default authService;
```

and these are my 4 components that manage the 4 phases (login - login callback - logout - logout callback)

`loadinglogin.tsx`:

```js
    import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { ColorRing } from 'react-loader-spinner';
    import { Button } from 'antd';
    import { withRouter } from '../../../helpers/rtrHelper';
    import authService, { AuthenticationResultStatus } from '../../../services/AuthService';
    import { getReturnUrl } from '../../../helpers/stringHelper';
    import { LoadingLoginProps } from '../../../interfaces';

    declare type LoginLoadingState = {
        message: string,
    };

    class LoadingLogin extends React.PureComponent<LoadingLoginProps, LoginLoadingState> {
        constructor(props: LoadingLoginProps) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                message: '',
            };
        }

        componentDidMount(): void {
            void this.login();
        }

        // componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<LoadingLoginProps>, prevState: Readonly<LoginLoadingState>, snapshot?: any): void {
        //     void this.login();
        // }

        // async setLogin() {
        //     this.setState({ message: 'loggin in...' });
        //     await this.login();
        // }

        login = async (): Promise<void> => {
            const redirectPath: string = getReturnUrl();
            const result = await authService.signin({ redirectPath });
            switch (result.status) {
                case AuthenticationResultStatus.Redirect:
                    break;
                case AuthenticationResultStatus.Success:
                    window.location.href = redirectPath;
                    break;
                case AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail:
                    this.setState({ message: 'An error occured' });
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Error(`Invalid status result ${result.status}.`);
            }
        };

        // <Button onClick={() => void this.setLogin()}>{message}</Button>
        render() {
            const { message } = this.state;

            return (
                message ? (
                    <strong>{message}</strong>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <ColorRing
                          colors={['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'magenta']}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(LoadingLogin);
```

`logincallback.tsx`

```js
    import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { ColorRing } from 'react-loader-spinner';
    import authService, { AuthenticationResultStatus } from '../../../services/AuthService';
    // import Loader from '../_Common/Loader';

    const LoginCallback: FC = function LoginCallBack() {
        const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
        const navigate = useNavigate();

        useEffect(() => {
            const processSigninCallback = async () => {
                const result = await authService.completeSignin();
                const newLocal = result.userState ? result.userState.redirectPath : '/';

                switch (result.status) {
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Redirect:
                        // There should not be any redirects as the only time completeSignIn finishes
                        // is when we are doing a redirect sign in flow.
                        throw new Error('Should not redirect.');
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Success:
                        navigate(newLocal);
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail:
                        setMessage(result.message);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Error(`Invalid authentication result status '${result.status}'.`);
                }
            };

            void processSigninCallback();
        }, [navigate]);

        return message ? <div>{message}</div> : (
            <ColorRing
              colors={['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'magenta']}
            />
        );
    };

    export default LoginCallback;
```

`loadinglogout.tsx`

```js
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
    import { ColorRing } from 'react-loader-spinner';
    import authService, { AuthenticationResultStatus } from '../../../services/AuthService';
    import { withRouter } from '../../../helpers/rtrHelper';
    import { LoadingLogoutProps } from '../../../interfaces';

    declare interface LoadingLogoutState {
        message: string,
    }

    class LoadingLogout extends PureComponent<LoadingLogoutProps, LoadingLogoutState> {
        public constructor(props: LoadingLogoutProps) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                message: '',
            };
        }

        componentDidMount(): void {
            this.logout();
        }

        // componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<LoadingLogoutProps>, prevState: Readonly<LoadingLogoutState>, snapshot?: any): void {
        //     void this.logout();
        // }

        logout = () => {
            const redirectPath = `${window.location.origin}/`;
            authService.signout()
            .then((result) => {
                switch (result.status) {
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Redirect:
                        console.log('LOGOUT REDIRECT');
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Success:
                        console.log(`LOGOUT SUCCESS - REDIRECT PATH: "${redirectPath}"`);
                        window.location.href = redirectPath;
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail:
                        this.setState({ message: 'An error occurred' });
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Error(`Invalid status result ${result.status}.`);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new Error('Invalid status result.');
            });
        };

        render(): React.ReactNode {
            const { message } = this.state;
            return message ? <div>{message}</div> : (
                <ColorRing
                  colors={['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'magenta']}
                />
            );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(LoadingLogout);
```

`logoutcallback.tsx`

```js
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
    import { ColorRing } from 'react-loader-spinner';
    import { LogoutCallbackProps } from '../../../interfaces';
    import authService, { AuthenticationResultStatus } from '../../../services/AuthService';
    import { withRouter } from '../../../helpers/rtrHelper';

    declare interface LogoutCallBackState {
        message: string,
    }

    class LogoutCallback extends PureComponent<LogoutCallbackProps, LogoutCallBackState> {
        public constructor(props: LogoutCallbackProps) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                message: 'ti sto scollegandooooOOOOOOOOOOOOO',
            };
        }

        componentDidMount(): void {
            this.processSignoutCallback();
        }

        // componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<LogoutCallbackProps>, prevState: Readonly<LogoutCallBackState>, snapshot?: any): void {
        //     void this.processSignoutCallback();
        // }

        processSignoutCallback = () => {
            const { navigate } = this.props;
            // const result = await authService.completeSignout();
            authService.completeSignout()
            .then((result) => {
                const newLocal = result.userState ? result.userState.redirectPath : '/';
                switch (result.status) {
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Success:
                        navigate(newLocal);
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationResultStatus.Fail:
                        this.setState({ message: result.message });
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Error('Invalid authentication result status.');
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new Error('Invalid authentication result status.');
            });
        };

        render(): React.ReactNode {
            const { message } = this.state;
            return <h1>LOHOUYNG</h1>;
            // return message ? <h1>{message}</h1> : (
            //     <ColorRing
            //       colors={['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'magenta']}
            //     />
            // );
        }
    }

    export default withRouter(LogoutCallback);
```

One thing I definitely noticed in debug is that in the `LoginCallback` component, the `processSigninCallback` function that I call in the `useState` hook is called twice, the first time `result.status` is `Fail` in my `switch` and the second is `Success` and I', being successfully redirected with the uploaded user.

these are my routes:
`App.tsx`

```js
    import React, { FC } from 'react';
    import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

    import PrivateOutlet from './privateOutlet';
    import PublicOutlet from './publicOutlet';
    import { defaultPagination } from '../context/defaults';
    // #region auth
    import LoadingLogin from '../lib/Components/Auth/LoadingLogin';
    import LoginCallback from '../lib/Components/Auth/LoginCallback';
    import LoadingLogout from '../lib/Components/Auth/LoadingLogout';
    import LogoutCallback from '../lib/Components/Auth/LogoutCallback';
    import SilentRenew from '../lib/Components/Auth/SilentRenew';
    // #endregion auth
    import Desk from '../lib/Components/Desk';
    import Login from '../lib/Components/Login';
    import ProductsPage from '../lib/Components/ProductsPage';
    import PersonalPage from '../lib/Components/PersonalPage';
    import VideosPage from '../lib/Components/VideosPage';
    import SingleVideoPage from '../lib/Components/SingleVideoPage';
    import PageNotFound from '../lib/Components/PageNotFound';
    import Header from '../lib/Components/Header';

    const App: FC = function App() {
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<PublicOutlet />}>
                    <Route index element={<Desk />} />
                    <Route path="prodotti" element={<ProductsPage />} />
                    <Route path="area_personale/:username" element={<PersonalPage />} />
                    <Route path="video" element={<VideosPage />} />
                    <Route path="video/:niceUrl" element={<SingleVideoPage />} />
                    <Route path="login" element={<LoadingLogin />} />
                    <Route path="signin-callback" element={<LoginCallback />} />
                    <Route path="logout" element={<LoadingLogout />} />
                    <Route path="signout-oidc" element={<LogoutCallback />} />
                    <Route path="silent-renew" element={<SilentRenew />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        );
    };

    export default App;
```

what could be the cause of this double call of which the first is always "broken", triggering the error of the state that does not match?

Comment: in my experience this error always happen when the configuration from server and the client is not match. there may be some miss or typo. double check please.

Comment: What is `router`?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

the problem is wrapping the whole app using `React.StrictMode`, somehow (only locally not in production) it makes double calls.
By removing it, double calls no longer occur

Comment: Yes. It's in the documentation here https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/render-and-commit under Pitfill with the text ->  "When developing in “Strict Mode”, React calls each component’s function twice, which can help surface mistakes caused by impure functions."